# How to clear middleware loading to make dynamic route loading?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, routes, middleware

I don't know if it's possible, but I need to loading dinamically route files in middleware, according to a conditional.

Here we have the code that do well job in the first request, but seems that in next request, he enters inside right place of conditional but not use right file, seems that he uses cache file or something of previous request...

```
let routesApp = require('./routes-app');
let routesWeb = require('./routes-web');

app.use((req, res, next) => {
    const regex = new RegExp(pattern, 'i')
    if (regex.test(req.headers['agent-type'])) {
        app.use('/', routesWeb)
    } else {
        app.use('/', routesApp)
    }
    return next()
})
```

How do I make this works?

Comment: You simply can't code this way.  You can't allow the headers of one request to your server from one user to change routes for all future requests from all requests.  There is no general purpose web server that serves the needs of many users that can/should be written that way or will work properly.  I'd suggest you back up and describe the overall problem you are really trying to solve (not your attempt at dynamic routes).

Comment: If I were to guess what you're trying to do, I'd say you should probably identify agent-type and then set a cookie that will be used to decide how to handle future requests.  You can't conditionally set routes that apply to only one user.  Servers don't/can't work that way.

Comment: If you want to use routing to separate app from web, then use a different path in your URL for web vs. app.  `/web/*` and `/app/*`.  Then, you can have completely separate routes for them.

Comment: I know that /web/ and /app/ works well for it, I'm just trying this method because I will not need to change my url, using same url for web and app, making header decides what route file use

Comment: In my app, if I send header agent-type of app, I load route of app. Same thing with web, but this code can make some user of both, load wrong file, like in my postman testing

Comment: Do you understand that once you do an `app.use()` that is in effect for ALL future requests from ALL users, not just the future requests from that one user.  You can't build a multi-user server this way.  Never install routes intended for a particular user from within routes.  Never.  Your thinking would only work if you only ever had this one user from that one device contacting your server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call `app.use` the middleware passed to it gets registered for that path and subsequent requests will be handled by that .

One way to handle what you are doing is define a middleware which conditionally delegates to your web or mobile middleware as needed.

Sample Code:

```
let routesApp = require('./routes-app');
let routesWeb = require('./routes-web');

app.use('/', (req, res, next) => {
    const regex = new RegExp(pattern, 'i')
    if (regex.test(req.headers['agent-type'])) {
        routesWeb(req, res, next);
    } else {
        routesApp(req, res, next);
    }
})
```

Comment: Except this requires that the `agent-type` header be present on all requests and I'm not sure that is the case.  If so, then this would indeed work if `routesWeb` and `routesApp` are coded to accept this function signature.

Comment: @jfriend00 Agreed. I assume the intent here is - match header to `pattern` to determine if it is for the Web (else if there is no match or the header is absent, default to the App routes). And yup, `routesWeb` and `routesApp` can be any other middleware-like function including an `express.Router` (which I'm guessing is what `routesWeb` and `routesApp` are ).

Comment: @ChiragRavindra It's exactly what you said, maybe I just need to be more specific next time adding more code and explanations, but thank you for the answer, it works now